# Why does the tag [map] turn into [dictionary] on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tags

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298381/what-is-going-on-in-this-map-string-array) about a map/string array on SO. I used the tags [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) [playframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playframework) and submitted the question. The tag [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) turned into [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) so I edited the question and removed the tag [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary). Shortly after that someone edited my post and added the tags [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) ([map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map)?) and removed the [playframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playframework) tag.

So is this a bug or do I not see the connection between "map" and "dictionary"?

(Non-native English speaker here.)

Comment: For the record, [the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30298381/revisions) was not done by a mod (mod's have diamonds next to their name like Oded).  It was done by a user with the privileges to edit posts.

Answer (score 6):

The map tag is a synonym of the dictionary tag:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dictionary/synonyms

This means that when you use the tag [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) on a question it will automatically be changed to [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary).

A map and a dictionary are essentially the same thing, as far as the programming concepts are concerned.

Comment: Well in both you look something up. Makes sense somehow

Comment: CAN YOUR DICTIONARY DO STREET VIEW?

Comment: @Pekka웃: Wrong kind of dictionary, mine is 2d.

Comment: this needs corrected to reflect the `map` function!

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, hash == dictionary but map == ... map.

Answer (score 1):

The [playframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playframework) tag was probably removed because your question actually has nothing to do with Play Framework.  We like to have our tags describe the actual question at hand.

Your question is about strings, arrays and dictionaries in Java, so that is what the tags were changed to.

Comment: Yeah I am ok with the removed `playframework` tag. I wasnt sure if I should mention the pf in my question as I thought the method `.asFormUrlEncoded();`might be something special in the playframework (my view class uses forms to get information into the controller class).

Comment: It is fine to mention it.  Back ground information is helpful.  It is just that tags are used to categorize questions, so they work a little different.